# How to fix AWS Cloud Formation Drift after Start and Stop of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a AWS Cloud Formation Stack. I Started and Stopped the EC2 instance in that stack. Now the stack is drifted and below are the drift results. How do I resolve this issue as Expected and Actual both are same.

[image]

Comment: I need some more information: Are these redacted values in "expected" and "actual" multi-valued or is this a single key-value pair?

Comment: Those values are not redacted those are the actual thing CFS is showing in Drift reults

Comment: That is very confusing since I cannot find any documentation about this CFN behaviour. Do you have 'ec2:DescribeInstances' permission when calling the drift detection as the docs mention the following: "In order to successfully perform drift detection on a stack, a user must have the following permissions:

Read permission for each resource that supports drift detection included in the stack. For example, if the stack includes an AWS::EC2::Instance resource, you must have ec2:DescribeInstances permission to perform drift detection on the stack."

Comment: Yes I am the root account holder. I started and stopped the instance and the public IP changed and now the stack is drifted

Comment: Is the 'NoEcho' attribute set somewhere in your cloud formation template?

Comment: It is a JSON template it does not have that No Echo Attribute in it @MartinLöper

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is related to restarting your [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html). I've both rebooted and stopped and started an instance using this template and the drift status is still `IN_SYNC` after running drift detection:

```
Parameters:
  ImageId:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2
Resources:
 Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ImageId
      Tags:
        - Key: Key
          Value: Value
```

Do the tags on the EC2 instance match the tags from the template?

Comment: Did you reboot or Start and Stopped the instance because both are 2 different things